# Error (10568): VHDL error at Questao1.vhd(44): can't write to interface object "dataa" of mode IN

Tags: vhdl

That's my code:

```
-- Insert library and use clauses
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY Questao1 IS
    -- Begin port declaration
    PORT (  
        -- Declare data inputs "dataa" and "datab"
        dataa, datab : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);

        -- Declare data output "sum"
        sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0)
    );
-- End entity 
END ENTITY Questao1;

--   Begin architecture 
ARCHITECTURE logic OF Questao1 IS
BEGIN

    sum <= x"000A" WHEN dataa = x"0001" ELSE x"000B" WHEN datab = x"0001" ELSE x"000C";


    dataa <= x"0001", x"0000" AFTER 20 NS, x"000A" AFTER 30 NS;
    datab <= x"0000", x"0001" AFTER 20 NS, x"0005" AFTER 30 NS;

-- End architecture
END ARCHITECTURE logic;
```

That's my error:

Error (10568): VHDL error at Questao1.vhd(44): can't write to interface object "dataa" of mode IN

Someone can help? I'm beginning in VHDL

Comment: `dataa` is an input. You cannot assign to it from the architecture body. If you want to assign something to it maybe it was meant to be an output?

Comment: Or did you mean to make an instance of `Questao1` and assign something to its inputs *from outside*?

Comment: I need to implement the following logical architecture: `sum <= x"000A" WHEN dataa = x"0001" ELSE
 x"000B" WHEN datab = x"0001" ELSE
 x"000C";`

Comment: The stimulus signals should be: `dataa <= x"0001", x"0000" AFTER 20 NS, x"000A" AFTER 30 NS;
 datab <= x"0000", x"0001" AFTER 20 NS, x"0005" AFTER 30 NS;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were a given a task to write a testbench to test your code.

Generally speaking a vhdl code for a design represents how the design should behave. If you wish to test it if it really does, what it is supposed to do, you need to 'wrap' it in a bigger device, to be able to send signals to your 'device under test'.
This is often done with the use of testbenches - a vhdl code that uses your entity as a component and sends signals to it.

Next thing to note is that any time specific commands (like 'AFTER' in your case) are not synthesizable. However you can simulate behaviour of your design using software tools, like modelsim.

Another thing is that you cannot assign values to input. Input ports receive data from 'outside world', you cannot alter the data your entity receives from within the entity itself.